# Effect of affectedStores on fetching unsaved NSManagedObjects?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8, nsfetchrequest, nspersistentstore

Here is a brief sequence that involves a Core Data stack with an (initially empty) `NSManagedObjectContext` and a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` with two `NSPersistentStore`s:

```
Player *player = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Player" 
                                               inManagedObjectContext: context];
player.playerID = playerID;
// (1) [context assignObject: player toPersistentStore: secondStore];

NSFetchRequest *requestForPlayer = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: @"Player"];
requestForPlayer.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"playerID == %@", playerID];
NSAssert(requestForPlayer.affectedStores == nil, nil); // inits to nil
// (2) requestForPlayer.affectedStores = @[ secondStore ];

players = [context executeFetchRequest: requestForPlayer error: &error];
```

This fetches one player. If I uncomment `(2`) (i.e. involve the second store) it fetches zero (sic!) players. If I uncomment also `(1)` it fetches again one player.

So it seems as if the behavior `NSFetchRequest` returns unsaved `NSManagedObject`s only if

1. either `affectedStores` is `nil` and those objects have not been assigned to any store
2. or `affectedStores` is not `nil` and those objects have been assigned to an affected store

Is this indeed the case and if so, where is this documented by Apple?

Comment: I can't find it documented either.  It's interesting that `NSFetchRequest` inherits from `NSPersistentStoreRequest` and yet you throw it at a MOC.  Anyways: you *have* seen that affectedStores inits to nil and not the PSC's first/last store/whatever? I'm not sure if you imply that intentionally in #1, or assume it.

Comment: @stevesliva 1. I guess an important reason for `NSFetchRequest` inheriting from `NSPersistentStoreRequest` is its convenient use as sibling of `NSSaveChangesRequest` in `NSIncrementalStore`'s  `executeRequest:withContext:error:`. 2. Yes I have seen that (unless there was a mistake). The (to me) somewhat surprising thing is that in this Q's context `affectedStores == nil` apparently denotes "first/last/whatever" if there is only store one but "none of these" if there are several stores.